# What causes a gyroscope to eventually rotate/fall over?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, vectors, torque

Hey so I've just learned about angular velocity and momentum and how torque changes it.

Looking at a [wheel spinning around an axis, with one end being held up](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8H98BgRzpOM) by a rope, what causes the wheel to rotate downwards over time, and eventually fall?

Comment: I didn't saw it rotating backwards, the only thing which i saw was that the wheel stops after some time, that can be easily attributed to the friction the ball bearing offers....

Answer (score 2):

Friction. The wheel is held up due to the effects of a torque on the angular momentum of the wheel; when the wheel no longer has angular momentum (because it stops spinning due to friction) precession no longer occurs. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precession) has more information on precession, but I think [this MIT video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zLy0IQT8ssk) gives a better intuition.